# How to install and run Telescope on Windows 7 (i.e. http://telesc.pe)

Tags: meteor

I couldn't get Meteorite and [Telescope](http://telesc.pe) running on windows 7, any **ideas how should we do this**?

---

Here's what I tried:

- installed Meteor on win7 using win.meteor.com
- tried to install Meteorite (following instructions on its Github page), but it threw
  couple errors (although it finished installation):

> C:\Users\Daler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteorite\node_modules\ddp\node_modules\w
>   s\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.D efault.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is correct , and that the file exists on
>   disk.
>
> C:\Users\Daler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteorite\node_modules\ddp\node_modules\w
>   s\build\validation.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.D efault.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is correct , and that the file exists on
>   disk.

- cloned Telescope, then ran it with `mrt` from its folder, but got errors about missing dependencies of Meteorite. manually copied "router" and "page-js" packages to "Meteor/packages" as [suggested here](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/65#issuecomment-11428236):

But still, running `mrt` or `mrt run` exits without error. 
However running with `meteor` command sometimes starts the server on localhost and then fails due to a missing file and sometimes cannot find/start MongoDB.

Comment: While Meteor has been unofficially ported to Windows, I'm not sure meteorite has, which may be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422) (as suggested by https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) fixed the `MSB4019` error for me doing `npm install xxx` on Windows7 x64.

The readme of that update states that the recommended order is

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Windows SDK 7.1
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
4. Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1